# Cannot print returned value in C

Tags: c, pointers, arguments

I ran compile this:

```
char get_credit_card_status(long long credit_card_number, char Luhn_validity)//, char credit_card_status)
{
    char credit_card_status = 0;
    if (((credit_card_number < 350000000000000) && (340000000000000 <=credit_card_number)) && (Luhn_validity=1))
    {
        credit_card_status = 1;
        printf("1 test\n");
    }
    else if ((5100000000000000<= credit_card_number) && (credit_card_number < 5500000000000000) && Luhn_validity)
    {
        credit_card_status = 2;
        printf("2 test\n");
    }
    else if ((((4000000000000<= credit_card_number)&&(credit_card_number<5000000000000)) || ((4000000000000000<=credit_card_number)&&(credit_card_number<5000000000000000))) && Luhn_validity)
    {
        credit_card_status= 3;
        printf("3 test\n");
    }
    return credit_card_status;
}

int length_ccn(long long credit_card_number)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (credit_card_number > 0)
    {
        length++;
        credit_card_number /= 10 ;
    }
    return length;
}

char Luhn_check(long long credit_card_number)
{
    int total_even_numbers = 0;
    int total_odd_numbers = 0;
    int even_number = 0;
    int odd_number = 0;
    int Luhn_sum = 0;
    char Luhn_validity = 0;
    long long check_digit_basis = credit_card_number;
    for(int i =1 ; check_digit_basis > 0 ; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 2) > 0)
        {
            odd_number = (check_digit_basis % 10);
            total_odd_numbers = total_odd_numbers + odd_number;
        }
        else
        {
            even_number = (check_digit_basis % 10);
            if(even_number >= 5)
            {
                total_even_numbers = total_even_numbers + ((( 2 * even_number) % 10) + 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                total_even_numbers = total_even_numbers + (2 * even_number);
            }
        }
        check_digit_basis = (check_digit_basis / 10);

    }
    Luhn_sum = total_even_numbers + total_odd_numbers;
    if ((Luhn_sum % 10 ) == 0 )
    {
        Luhn_validity = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Luhn_validity = 0;
        printf("%c for Luhn_validity\n", Luhn_validity);
    }
    printf("%d for Luhn_validity\n", Luhn_validity);
    return Luhn_validity;
}



int main(void)
{
    printf("Provide your credit card number:\n");
    long long credit_card_number = get_long_long();
    int length = length_ccn(credit_card_number);
    printf("%i for length\n", length);
    char Luhn_validity = Luhn_check(credit_card_number);
    printf("%c returned from line 119\n", Luhn_validity);
    char credit_card_status;
    credit_card_status = get_credit_card_status(credit_card_number, Luhn_validity);
    switch (credit_card_status)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("American Express\n");
        break;

        case 2:
        printf("MasterCard\n");
        break;

        case 3:
        printf("Visa\n");
        break;

        default:
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```

I got:

```
15 for length
1 for Luhn_validity
 returned from line 119
```

The value of `Length` is returned to the main function while `Luhn_validity` isn't. Why?

I cannot make another post because someone posted an incomplete answer only answering to what I already began to implement (see the post before its edits and you'll see that the boolean problem was being corrected and wasn't in the post's title).

Comment: show the whole code for `Luhn_check`

Comment: An expression like `a<=x<b` is not what you want. You need to write it as `a<=x && x<b`.

Comment: `credit_card_status = credit_card_status(credit_card_number)` -- do you see that you are repeating names? And that is precisely where the error is.

Comment: better use also an 'else' statement not only 'else if' otherwise credit_card_status could be undefined.

Comment: `credit_card_status = American Express` -- what is this even supposed to mean?

Comment: Also for long int literals use the correct suffix otherwise it will not work.

Comment: For questions related to *cs50* try https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I edited my message to show you everything.
The Luhn_check is working. In fact, everything was working before I tried to implement the credit_card_status. It was formerly named get_credit_card_status but I got errors and thought that I had to modify the name.

Answer (score 2):

```
credit_card_status = credit_card_status(credit_card_number)
```

You try to use the same name, `credit_card_status`, for two different things. If the function is called `credit_card_status` don't store it's return value in `credit_card_status`, because that's the function and not a variable. This leads to the error that `credit_card_status` is not assignable.

> error: comparison of constant 350000000000000 with boolean expression is always true

There is no "twoway" comparison `a <= x < b` in C, you have to use two separate comparisons: `a <= x && x < b`.

Comment: In the original post, you can see that the solution to the bolean problem already got partially implemented. The first part of your answer don't get any way to solve my problem.